# Photo looks different after saving

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I'm pretty sure that there's something in computer that causes that. Everytime I render (save) a picture from Photoshop or Lightroom somehow it gains more contrast. I tried lots of tutorials, was switching and testing color profiles and I've found nothing.

Intresting thing that I can take a picture screen by uploading it to internet and everything is all right till I save the picture on my PC. It somehow renders and makes the photo different. (It gains more contrast).

My laptop has same default settings in Lightroom and it does its job very well.

Wheres the problem in my PC with photo rendering/saving issue? I would appreciate your help.

Comment: Hi there! I'll migrate this question to Superuser, as it's not really about graphic design. Good luck!

Comment: Photoshop and some other serious image manipulation programs incorporate a screen adjustment utility that fine tunes the colors displayed so that you can better adjust images.  It lets you distinguish more dark greys and near whites.  This is a lot less contrasty than what people like for normal use.  The default setting for monitors is often a higher contrast because it makes things brighter and easier to see (and people think the monitor has a nicer image when they compare it in the store even though that setting is less accurate).